# How can I migrate mails from Yahoo! Mail to Google Apps?

Tags: email, migration, google-workspace, yahoo-mail

We'd like to move from using Yahoo! Mail to our Google Apps account.

It'd be great to be able to migrate all the mails across from the old accounts to the new. If we were using Gmail accounts this would be easy as the migration is offered by Google, for some reason they don't offer this to those using custom domains. As far as I know Yahoo! don't offer POP or IMAP access to non-paying customers and I'd rather not pay $20 per account that I want to migrate.

Anyone know of any easy and cheap solutions?

Comment: Questions on Web services are out of scope of SuperUser.

Comment: But questions about computer software are in scope. As the answers show, this is a question about software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure POP access to Yahoo for free, by using [YPOPs](http://ypopsemail.com/).

Or, using Thunderbird, you can use the [Webmail Add-on](http://webmail.mozdev.org/), that integrates website-based email accounts, allowing Thunderbird to download and to send emails using the web sites of Yahoo, Hotmail, MailDotCom, Gmail, Libero, and AOL domains.

Comment: Awesome! I always just told people don't even bother with Yahoo, and if you have it you're SOL unless you pay the monthly fee. However, that program, though I haven't verified whether it works, seems to be the solution everyone wants! Cool.

Answer (score 2):

The google migration tool works really well at maintaining the archived email information - such as the proper date.  If you use a free tool to download via pop then all of your old email will have the date that you downloaded them.

Pay the $20 and establish an IMAP account with your email client.  Use one that the google email uploader supports (http://mail.google.com/mail/help/email_uploader.html) and let it go to work.

Your thousands of historical email may become nearly useless if they all have the date 5/14/2010...

Comment: +1, Totally agree, If you want to keep the date settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using YPop! with GetMail ? Hope this article helps --> [MigrateYahooToGmail](http://www.e-eeasy.com/MigrateYahooToGmail.aspx)
Even though  it talks about Yahoo to Gmail, It should work for Google Apps as well